# 999 response when trying to crawl LinkedIn with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying the Scrapy framework to extract some information from LinkedIn.
I am aware that they are very strict with people trying to crawl their website, so I tried a different user agent in my settings.py. I also specified a high download delay but it still seems to block me right off the bat.

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = False
DEPTH_LIMIT = 5
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10
REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 20
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
```

This is the error I receive:

```
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
127.0.0.1:6023
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (999) <GET
https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-1/> (referer: None) ['cached']
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response
<999 https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-1/>: HTTP status code is not handled or 
not allowed
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 282,
'downloader/request_count': 1,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
'downloader/response_bytes': 2372,
'downloader/response_count': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/999': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20, 17, 11, 29, 503000),
'httpcache/hit': 1,
'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
'log_count/INFO': 8,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20, 17, 11, 29, 378000)}
2017-03-20 19:11:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The spider itself just prints the visited url.

```
class InfoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "info"
    allowed_domains = ["www.linkedin.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-1/']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=[r'.*']),
            callback='parse',
            follow=True)
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you scraping personal data too? It is one thing to ignore a terms of service - I don't personally think they are necessarily binding - but it is quite another to take and reuse personal data without the permission of the affected individuals.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not going to use any of the data. I am just learning Scrapy and trying to understand how itworks in a scenario like this one.

Comment: Did you get this to work with scrapy? if yes, can you update your question and add the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to login linkedin first before crawl any other pages. To login with scrapy, you can refer to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects

UPDATE 1:
here is an example of my code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from linkedin.items import *

class LinkedinSpider(InitSpider):

"""
Define the crawler's start URIs, set its follow rules, parse HTML
and assign values to an item. Processing occurs in ../pipelines.py
"""

name = "linkedin"
allowed_domains = ["linkedin.com"]
user_name = 'my_user_name'
passwd = 'my_passwd'

# Uncomment the following lines for full spidering
# start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-%s-%d-%d-%d"
#               % (alphanum, num_one, num_two, num_three)
#                 for alphanum in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#                 for num_one in xrange(1,11)
#                 for num_two in xrange(1,11)
#                 for num_three in xrange(1,11)
#               ]

# Temporary start_urls for testing; remove and use the above start_urls in production
# start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-a-23-23-2"]
start_urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com/in/rebecca-liu-93a12a28/"]
login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
# TODO: allow /in/name urls too?
# rules = (
#     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\/pub\/.+')),
#          callback='parse_item'),
# )

def init_request(self):
    return Request(url=self.login_page,callback=self.login)

def login(self,response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
        'session_key':user_name,'session_password':passwd
    },
                                     callback = self.check_login_response)

def check_login_response(self,response):
    return self.initialized()
```

**Do remember** to call **self.initialized()** if you are using **InitSpider**, or the **parse()** method won't be called.

Answer (score 3):

Notice **headers** carefully in the requests. **LinkedIn** requires the following headers in each requests to serve the response.

```
headers = {
    "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "accept-language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6",
    "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
}
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still get a 999 response even if I use the headers you provided, though.  In Scrapy shell :  `>>> headers = { ... } >>> req = Request('linkedin.com/directory/people-1/', headers=headers) >>> fetch(req)   {...}  2017-03-20 21:00:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (999)`

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. Although i used **lxml** to test it.
With only `user-agent` as header, i was also getting **999** status code.

Comment: I passed {'referer': ''} in the headers to make 999 go away.