# Not getting any output when i run the spider

Tags: scrapy

I tried to scrape linkedin profiles of some people belonging to a company. I used a rotating proxy. But when I run the script I get back no results and also I'm getting no errors. I can't find out what I am doing wrong here. Can someone please point out what I;m doing wrong. (I'm still a beginner)m

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class LinkedinSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'linkedin'
    allowed_domains = ['www.linkedin.com']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/citi/people/?facetGeoRegion=sg%3A0%2Cbd%3A0&facetSchool=13432", headers= {
            "User-Agent": self.user_agent
        })
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths= "//a[@class='ember-view link-without-visited-state']"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers["User-Agent"] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath("//li[@class='inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words']").get()
        }
```

The terminal after I run the script. [image: Terminal Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910269/999-response-when-trying-to-crawl-linkedin-with-scrapy). If you set

```
 headers = {
    "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "accept-language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6",
    "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
}
```

in scrapy shell, You can get response 200. but then you will not able to get the right data. So you have to login in first.Then you can try to get the data.